# How to make hyperref work with \citetitle?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I want to create a link in between `\citetitle{}` and the bibliography entry using `hyperref` (as it does when I use the `\cite{}` command). How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\usepackage[natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\title{title}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

\citetitle{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a wee bit more information about your document setup. E.g., how or where is `\citetitle` defined? Where or how is the macro used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you're using `biblatex` and one of its standard styles, where `\citetitle` is defined in [`biblatex.def` (ll. 2156-2165 for v3.15)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/e5d6e69e61613cc33ab1fcc2083a8277eb9cfce5/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2156-L2165) as

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

If you want the output of that command linked, just add `\printtext[bibhyperref]{...}` in the appropriate place.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
     \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

ipsum \citetitle{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Linked citetitle output.]

---

If my guess about `biblatex` and your style is wrong and this solution does not work for you, please consider editing your question to include more details about your current citation and bibliography setup. Ideally in the form of a minimal example document not unlike the example document shown here. It is always a good idea to include such an example document to avoid misinterpretation and to give people something to start from.

Comment: Thank you @moewe. You helped me much. Sorry for not putting a MWE straight away.